# Babel error: repl: We found a path that isn't a NodePath instance. Possiblly due to bad serialisation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When running the code snippet (taken from a [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) regarding the `let` keyword in ES2015) through the [online Babel transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20list%20%3D%20document.getElementById(%22list%22)%3B%0A%0Afor%20(var%20i%20%3D%201%3B%20i%20%3C%3D%205%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20item%20%3D%20document.createElement(%22LI%22)%3B%0A%20%20item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(%22Item%20%22%20%2B%20i))%3B%0A%0A%20%20let%20j%20%3D%20i%3B%0A%20%20item.onclick%20%3D%20function%20(ev)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Item%20%22%20%2B%20j%20%2B%20%22%20is%20clicked.%22)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20list.appendChild(item)%3B%0A%7D), it fails with the following error:

```
repl: We found a path that isn't a NodePath instance. Possiblly due to bad serialisation.
```

Code

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement("LI");
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item " + i));

  let j = i;
  item.onclick = function (ev) {
    console.log("Item " + j + " is clicked.");
  };
  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

Why is the error thrown and what can I do about?

Comment: It works if you don't access `j` in the event handler. The Babel repl was just recently updated to use v6. Maybe you found a bug. I'd file an issue about it.

Comment: Relevant bug tracker: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7198